# Should I book tickets of flight before getting visa?

Tags: france, student-visa

I am going from a third world country to  France for masters study. I am going abroad for the first time and no one from my family or friends have ever been abroad.

> So, there was a question in my mind.

I will apply for visa in a couple of days. My classes are from 27 august. Should I book tickets to France before applying or getting visa (I can book ticket based on expected date of my travel so that I can save money and get flight cheap) or after getting an visa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will apply for a French visa through the French Embassy in India. [The official French government website](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/) contains a [visa wizard](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa); by entering your data into the wizard, you will be shown a list of the documents you'll need for your application.

I don't know your specifics, so (for demonstration purposes) I made them up:

[image]

The results page said you need a visa (you knew this already), unless you are...and then there's list of things you're not: e.g., a foreign national with a French resident permit, EU citizen, holder of a long-term EU resident permit, etc.) Thus, you do need a visa.

Then selecting plans as "study" and "main purpose of stay" as "Student, clicking on "Search" causes the wizard to display this list of required documents:

> **Supporting documents required**
>
> The Supporting documents to be provided are as follows:
>
> Pre-requisites
>
> - A travel document [passport], issued less than 10 years ago, containing at least two blank pages, with a period of validity at least 3 months longer than the date on which you intend to leave the Schengen Area or, in the case of a long stay, at least three months longer than the expiry date of the visa requested. Be sure to transmit (scan) ALL PAGES of your travel document containing visas, entry and exit stamps or any other inscription.  *(Bracketed material added)*
> - ID photograph.
> - If you are not a national of your country of residence: proof that you are legally resident in that country (e.g. residence permit).
> - If you have an official travel document [passport of a governmental official], a note verbale is required. *(Bracketed material added)*
>
> Purpose of travel/stay
>
> - Country following the EEF-Etudes en France procedure : Certificate of pre-registration generated by the EEF-Pastel application, stating the EEF ID number. Country outside of the EEF-Etudes en France procedure : Certificate of pre-registration (or registration) in an establishment of higher education or training.
> - Last completed degree (countries out of procedure EEF-Etudes en France).
>
> Funds
>
> - Proof of a minimum monthly income of €615 : certificate of scholarship or bank statement showing a deposit in a French bank account, or bank statement of permanent and irrevocable transfer (or blocked account), or an undertaking to accept financial liability from a guarantor who must provide proof of adequate, reliable and regular income, as well as a copy of their ID document.
>
> Accommodation
>
> - Proof of accommodation : hotel reservation, rental agreement, sworn statement/undertaking from the host (establishment/institution or private individual) or explanatory letter from the student detailing how the accommodation is planned.

And there is another information box following, setting forth the costs.

There is no mention that you must make flight reservations before submitting your application.

Finally: you must fill out the wizard by yourself, with your personal details accurate, in order for the displayed information to be correct.

Comment: In addition to this answer (+1) although this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51048/schengen-visa-application-what-are-some-helpful-tips-for-preparing is about a short term visa, it might be a helpful read